# SinglePageApplication design patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, single-page-application, online-repository

Does anyone know good book to cover all aspects of modern SPA development? I mean not only link to Angular/Angular2/Backbone/Ember etc, but maybe some aggregation of design approaches mapped to nowadays reality:

- Offile support
- Real-time communication
- Microservices architecture (reliability / scalability / availability)
- Mobile-first approach and native mobile applications
- Full-stack (MEAN / ?)
- Event-driven design
- UI -> frontend-backend -> backend-backend architecture

Everething separately can be found and already adopted, but maybe someone know interesting resources, forums, books where new approaches are discussed or really innovative decisions are made which encapsulate most or all topics above?

Thanks.